# Вывод дату по отдельности. Php

Tags: php

помогите пожалуйста вывести дату по отдельно. Хотя бы число дня, месяц.

у новости,есть таймштамп в поле ts, соотв. можно добыть дату и месяц.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать.

Есть что было, выводит дату:

Что предложили:
date('m', ...)
date('d', ...)

Но ничего не понял(

Буду сильно благодарен.

Comment: Предалагю почитать [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) - в ней есть примеры использования функции

Comment: 1 вариант, если вы говорите о timestamp, значит есть БД и можно заставить базу в запросе сразу вернуть день и месяц даты отдельно. 2 вариант - в php из полученной даты достать и то, и другое. В чём трудность-то? Где ваши собственные попытки и код?

Comment: Да говорю о timestamp

Comment: Покажите пример входных данных и пример желаемого результата

Comment: <?= $news_item['date'] ?> - при использовании данного кода выводится, дата размещения новости, а именно в таком формате - 08.09.2020. Мне нужно вывести эту дату по отдельности,  а именно число, месяц (словами) по отдельности.

сказали у новости,есть таймштамп в поле ts, соотв. можно добыть дату и месяц. А как вывести не могу понять.

Comment: Вас в первом же комментарии отправили в документацию, там много всего. ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас $news_item['date'] переменная равна 08.09.2020
Разбиваем ее на массив, где точка будет разбивать строку на массив:

```
$date = explode(".", $news_item['date']);
```

далее чтоб вывести дату 08:

```
echo $date[0];
```

далее чтоб вывести месяц 09:

```
echo $date[1];
```

далее чтоб вывести год 2020:

```
echo $date[2];
```

Если месяц нужно буквами, то размести функцию на верху где нить

```
function month($month) {
    if ($month == '01') {return 'январь';}
    else if ($month == '02') {return 'февраль';}
    else if ($month == '03') {return 'март';}
    else if ($month == '04') {return 'апрель';}
    else if ($month == '05') {return 'май';}
    else if ($month == '06') {return 'июнь';}
    else if ($month == '07') {return 'июль';}
    else if ($month == '08') {return 'август';}
    else if ($month == '09') {return 'сентябрь';}
    else if ($month == '10') {return 'октябрь';}
    else if ($month == '11') {return 'ноябрь';}
    else if ($month == '12') {return 'декабрь';}
}
```

а месяц выводи вот таким способом

```
echo month($date[1]);
```